# c: string entered not recognised

Tags: c, string, input, char

Given below is a piece of code that does not do what I want

```
do
{
    printf("inserisci un nome: ");
    scanf("%29s", s);
} while (s!="*");
```

My aim is to exit from the cycle if the string entered is "*".
Why doesn't it work?
What should I modify?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [strcmp](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/) to compare strings, `!=` will not do what you want.

In that case `!=` will compare the variable `s` (a **pointer** to the first element of the array `s`) with the string `"*"`. That is why it was not working properly.

Comment: if this answer helped, could you marked as the accepted answer? @IuTub